# NANOPOOL API to Python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, python-requests

For a little project on Arduino, i'm trying to read information of my miners on NANOPOOL with PYTHON.

But, there is a problem, and i don't find the solution.

This is my code:

```
import requests
address='t1UtZktQLxzxyonziphEsrXzD6xdLheevQH'
content=requests.get('https://api.nanopool.org/v1/zec/avghashrate/:address', params=address)
data=content.json()
t=data['data']['h1']
print(t)
```

API nanopool : https://zec.nanopool.org/api#api-Miner-AverageHashrates

I should receive "624.16" with this example : 
    {
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "h1": 624.16,
        "h3": 679.30,
        "h6": 719.41,
        "h12": 691.21,
        "h24": 636.37
    }
}

But i receive "0"

I think it is a problem with address, but i don't find a solution !
Someone can help me ?

Comment: I tried to replicate the request on [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) . Same response. Seems to be a problem with the API.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solve ! i must insert the adresse in the url like that : https://api.nanopool.org/v1/zec/avghashrate/t1UtZktQLxzxyonziphEsrXzD6xdLheevQH